# SSMS Uncomment Selected shortcut no longer working

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I make frequent use of SSMS's shortcut keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K, C</kbd>, to comment a block of code, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K, U</kbd> to uncomment.

Today, I went to do this, and noticed that<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K, U</kbd> no longer works. Instead, it shifts focus to the availabile databases dialog in the top left of the screen, which apparently has the shortcut of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

I have checked the settings and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K, U</kbd> is still mapped to uncomment selected code, but this is flat out not working.

Is this a bug, or something that I can fix?

SSMS v17.8.1

Comment: Considering that SSMS 14 is SSMS 2017, which hasn't updated in some time, this suggests that you, or someone, has changed the shortcut keys. I would suggest rebinding them in the Options Menu. They're in the Keyboard Pane; just type in "comment " in the search box and you'll see them both.

Comment: Note, as well, according to my versions of SSMS (2018 and 2017), the default binding is `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C` **not** `Ctrl+K,C` (and `U` respectively). I *assume* therefore you changed the default bindings previously.

Comment: Not sure if you can also see this is SSMS 14 *but* in the v18 and higher you can see the entered key combination in the bottom left of the window. Can you see that and is it correct (expected)?

Comment: @Larnu - as per my post, the command is still mapped as it should be. Also defaults have not been changed..

Comment: @Igor - the status bar down the bottom says 'CTRL+K was pressed, Waiting for second key of chord...'. Pressing U has no effect, pressing CTRL+U has the effect I described in my original post

Comment: You say you're doing `Ctrl+K,U` in your question, @Cam , *not* `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U`. `Ctrl+K,U` is not the default binding for the shortcut you describe, and we're getting conflicting statements now from you on what command you're actually trying.

Comment: On the keyboard pane, select the "Press Shortcut Keys" text box, then do `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U`. What commands do you see in "shortcut currently used by"?

Comment: @Larnu sorry let me try and be specific - I hold down the CTRL key, I press K, then I press U, then I release the CTRL key. This has always worked in the past. I have also tried CTRL + K, releasing CTRL, then CTRL + U, it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with ApexSQL refactor addin. I disabled it and the keyboard shortcut is working again.

Answer (score 3):

ApexSQL made patch to fix this problem

[Choose Get updates for ApexSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGJJF.png)

[Check show patches and press update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUrNl.png)

Comment: Thanks for your respone - funnily enough they made the patch off the back of a support ticket I submitted to them :)